# CircleCI - Conditional based on ENV Vars

Tags: circleci

We are migrating from Jenkins, to CircleCI for our image builds.

Our developers fork our repo's.

So we tag images 1 of 3 ways.

```
fork-name-gitsha <-- forked pull
repo-gitsha. <-- Pull from our actual repo
repo-branch-gitsha <- Merge to Master
```

In Circle CI, a Forked pull request contains this ENV Var.

`CIRCLE_PR_USERNAME`

But Pull requests from the main repo, or merges to master do not contain this.

Is there a way to do a conditional in CircleCI, based on an ENV var? I can only find examples for parameters.

basically something like..

```
  - when:
      condition: $CIRCLE_PR_USERNAME
      steps:
        - run:
            name: Set FULL_IMAGE_NAME
            command: echo 'export FULL_IMAGE_NAME="${CIRCLE_CI_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}/<< parameters.respository >>:${CIRCLE_PR_USERNAME}-${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}"' >> $BASH_ENV
        - run:
            name: Set IMAGE_TAG
            command: echo 'export IMAGE_TAG="${CIRCLE_CI_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}/<< parameters.respository >>:${CIRCLE_PR_USERNAME}-${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}"' >> $BASH_ENV
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use environment variables in logic statements.

Logic statements are [evaluated at configuration compilation time](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference#logic-statements), whereas environment variables are interpolated at run time.

You might want to look into [CircleCI dynamic configuration](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config).